# Change a static variable defined in superclass before making call from subclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have `classA` with static `PooledConnectionFactory` variable. `classB` extends A.

```
public class A{
    private static PooledConnectionFactory con;
    public A(){
        this("gets URL from defaults properties file");
    }
    public A(final String url){
       if(con==null){
         //Initialize pooled connection       
       }
//code for connection here
    }
}
```

```
public class B extends A {

    private PooledConnectionFactory conn;

    public B(String url){
        super(url);

    }


    public B(){
        super();
    }

}
```

I want to `PooledConnectionFactory` as a non-static variable so that for every service picked up, it is initialized separately. Since it is extending A, the call goes to constructors of A.

What changes should I make in class B to achieve this?

Comment: Just remove the `static`? I can't see any problems.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you want to make `con` non-static? What's keeping you from doing it? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm making changes to existing product, to make sure new changes don't affect original flow I was making changes in different class

Comment: Should both `con` objects be the same? In that case, make the one from `B` `protected` and remove the `conn` from `A`.

Comment: @qomzwinx Yes, but what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want different instances of `B` to use a different factory, even in the superclass methods? That's not possible without changing `A`.

Comment: Yes. For all the instances spawned in new class, I want a new pool connection to be established. in current flow, it checks for factory as null for second instance

Comment: @OhleC  I want the connectionFactory to be non static when accessed from class B

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton instead of `A` constructor

```
public class A {

    private static PooledConnectionFactory con;

    public A() {
        this("gets URL from defaults properties file");
    }

    public A(final String url) { }

    public static PooledConnectionFactory getPooledConnectionFactory() {
        if (con == null) {
            //Initialize pooled connection
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```